# Why doesnt this hover trigger text animation?

Tags: html, css

Trying to add a hover in a CMS program that only allows internal css. Please note that, while there is no head tag, the CMS recognizes  tags and automatically places them in the .

I've tried exporting as html to work through the issue but so far no luck. Tried using hierarchy by placing the resting state as H1 and hover state as a div class and as an ID. This is to be used through EKTRON CMS running html5 with no accessibility to js.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #1C7CB3;
}

h1 span:nth-child(even) {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  color: purple;
  letter-spacing: -1em;
}

h1:hover span:nth-last-child(even) {
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>F</span><span>lorida</span>
  <span>I</span><span>nstitute</span>
  <span></span><span>of</span>
  <span>E</span><span>ducation</span>
</h1>
```

I expected the text to animate but the text stays static.

Comment: you have 8 elements so `nth-last-child` will not target the same as `nth-child` when used with `even`

Comment: You're right! Completely overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hover effect you are using the `:nth-last-child(even)` selector. This will select every even element starting from the last. That is it will have it's first odd element being `<span>ducation</span>` and it's first even being `<span>E</span>`. You instead would want to use the `:nth-child(even)` to select from the start.

```
h1:hover span:nth-child(even)
{ 
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
```